# Sql substring using "/" as indicator where to cut

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

Hi I want to cut a string in sql at 2 points with the "/" as an indicator where to cut. The string looks like this: "test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6" and I need the parts of test 2 and test 5 but they are not static, so I have to use the "/" befor and after them to set the points where to cut, any suggestions?

Comment: In SQL Server 2016, you can use the built-in `split_string()`.  For earlier versions, you can search for such a function on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function CHARINDEX()
For example this query will work for you

```
declare @text varchar(100)='test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6'

select 
    SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1),
    SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1)+1)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1)
```

Just incase you want to substring something else, I'm sharing the code below and then you can work on it

```
declare @text varchar(100)='test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6'

select 
SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1)  --test2
,SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1)  --test3
,SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1)  --test4
,SUBSTRING (@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text,CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1)+1)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('/',@text,(CHARINDEX('/',@text)+1))-CHARINDEX('/',@text)-1) --test5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using XML:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(100) = 'test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6';
DECLARE @xml XML = cast(('<X>'+replace(@x,'/' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml);

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT(0))) AS rn
    FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn IN (1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the items that you want are always the second and the second to last you can use `CHARINDEX` to find the first and second '/' and `SUBSTRING` to pull that value. Then `REVERSE` the string to get the second last. e.g.

```
DECLARE @data varchar(128) = 'test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6';

SELECT substring(@data,charindex('/',@data,1)+1,charindex('/',@data,charindex('/',@data,1)+1)-(charindex('/',@data,1)+1)),
       reverse(substring(reverse(@data),charindex('/',reverse(@data),1)+1,charindex('/',reverse(@data),charindex('/',reverse(@data),1)+1)-(charindex('/',reverse(@data),1)+1)))
```